# Strange situation with font-awesome and bootstrap, at first click start working but after the third click does not work

Tags: click, font-awesome

I am using font-awesome like this:

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-primary text-primary"><small>
    <input id="town_id" type="checkbox" value="town_id" name="location[]"> 
    <label for="town_id">Bucharest</label></small>
</div>
```

I have a list with a lot of checkboxes, it's inside a bootstrap modal.

- Now, at the first click everything's ok, my checkbox is checked. I saw with inspect element in browser and it has been assigned to input checked="checked"
- At the second click, my input is unchecked, checked attribute is removed from input tag
- At the third click, input received the checked attribute, but the checkbox not showed checked
- Now, at the fourth click, it stops working, the checked attribute is not removed

I am using this code to check and change the status of checkbox:

```
if($("#"+id).is(':checked')){ 
    $("#"+id).attr('checked',false);
} else { 
    $("#"+id).attr('checked', true);
}
```

at the first click $("#"+id).is(':checked') return false, the second return true, the third return false, and than I have just false

Comment: And my question is, where is the problem? what I did wrong ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but where is the font-awesome in this example? It always uses classes that begin with "fa" and "fa-".